# $\sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq n, i|n, j|n} gcd(i,j)$

Tags: summation, gcd-and-lcm

> $$S = \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq n, i|n, j|n} gcd(i,j)$$

I can't find a way to solve this. Can I find a general formula or a way to solve this?

Comment: What is the meaning of $i|n$ here

Comment: @MayankDeora I divides n. :P

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r}$ be the prime factorization of the integer $n\geq 1$. The factorizations of the two divisors $i$ and $j$ of $n$ are $i=p_1^{k_1}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$ and $j=p_1^{l_1}\cdots p_r^{l_r}$, where $0\leq k_1,l_1\leq e_1$, $\ldots$, $0\leq k_r,l_r\leq e_r$. Your sum is then
\begin{align*}
S &~=~
\sum_{0\,\leq\, k_1,\,l_1\leq\, e_1,\,\,\ldots\,,\,\,0\,\leq\, k_r,\,l_r\leq\, e_r}
p_1^{\min(k_1,\,l_1)}\cdots\, p_r^{min(k_r,\,l_r)} \\[1ex]
&~=~\sum_{0\,\leq\, k_1,\,l_1\leq\, e_1}\!p_1^{\min(k_1,\,l_1)}
~\cdots\sum_{0\,\leq\, k_r,\,l_r\leq\, e_r}\!p_r^{min(k_r,\,l_r)}~~.
\end{align*}
It remains to calculate
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{0\,\leq\, k,\,l\,\leq\, e}p^{\min(k,\,l)}
\,=\, \sum_{m=0}^e(2m+1)\,p^{e-m}
\,=\, \frac{p^{\,e+2}+p^{\,e+1}-p\,(2e+3)+2\,e+1}{(p-1)^2}~~.
\end{equation*}
Write the rightmost expression above as $f(p,e)$. Then
\begin{equation*}
S = f(p_1,e_1)\cdots f(p_r,e_r)~.
\end{equation*}
Done.